# How to recover or manage orphaned POSIX semaphores

Tags: posix, semaphore

I am just starting to work with POSIX semaphores on Linux.   (I have used similar constructs in other OS).  My question is more about how to manage semaphores if I kill my application (because they or something else is misbehaving as I am going up the learning curve)

For example:

--I start the application, it creates the semaphores, and the semaphores work as expected.

--Something else does not work, so I kill the application (CTRL-C).

--When I re-start the application, the semaphore part no longer works.  I either get an **EACCES** error, or **EEXIST** error (depending on whether or not I used O_EXCL for `sem_open()`).

I can go to */dev/shm* and see the semaphores are still there.  If I manually delete these, the application works again.

Is there a better way to manage this?  Such as when the application starts up, if the semaphore exists, it can be reset and re-used, or else deleted and re-created.  This is the application that "owns" the semaphore, and ultimately I do not want it to rely on external actions to work.

Thanks!  for any advice.

EDIT: A related concern:  I would use these for inter-process communication. If the "owner process" of the semaphore is restarted, it could attempt to reset by `sem_close()` and then `sem_open()`.  However, if another process already has the semaphore, then there is an issue here. The behavior for `sem_destroy()` is undefined in this case.  Maybe I need to consider something other than semaphores here...

Comment: The answer depends on the programming language you're using. In C++ I would use an RAII wrapper to solve this problem. A wrapper to create them another wrapper that binds increasing and decreasing into a single object. In any way, you might have to deal with handling signals.

Comment: RAII will not solve problems due to aborts.